# _getTab() returns spaces

Tags: joomla-3.x, jfactory

Why does the following code return two spaces instead of one tab?
How can I change this setting easily?

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$tab = $document->_getTab();
```

[reference](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDocument.html)

Answer (score 3):

Two spaces are hard coded in `protected static function createDocument()` located inside `libraries/joomla/factory.php`:

```
$attributes = array(
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'lineend' => 'unix',
        'tab' => '  ',
        'language' => $lang->getTag(),
        'direction' => $lang->isRTL() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr',
        'mediaversion' => $version->getMediaVersion()
    );
```

which overrides previous class property declaration of `\11` in `libraries/joomla/document/document.php` and all rows in the head section become indented with 2 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the method documentation, it is doing exactly what its supposed to.  Which is return the system default for the number of spaces a keyboard tab event contains.

Below is the method as taken from JDocument class:

```
/**
 * Returns a string containing the unit for indenting HTML
 *
 * @return  string
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public function _getTab()
{
    return $this->_tab;
}
```

And the class property for $_tab:

```
/**
 * Tab string
 *
 * @var    string
 * @since  11.1
 */
public $_tab = "\11";
```

Using the above and referencing the PHP Documents for Escape Sequences in text we see a reference to exact string:

```
\11
might be a back reference, or another way of writing a tab
```

You can visit the below link for more info, but the method in question returns the PHP escape sequence for a tab.

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: Hm, not a Joomla guru, but can not find exactly this.
In document.php :
    `public $_tab = "\11";`
from php docs - \11 - might be a back reference, or another way of writing a tab

Comment: see my edit for further clarification

Comment: Thank you, but this do not answer my question, and it was way _getTab() returns two spaces (#20, #20), instead of one tab char (#09)? As far I understand from escape sequence \11 stands for octal 11 which is hex 09 (tab char). Somewhere, later this single tab is substituted with two spaces. Is it possible to be a template issue as well.

Comment: Search your code base for "setTab(". The tab character can be changed, and somewhere in your install it is being changed to two spaces.

Comment: I made fresh new install of latest Joomla (3.3.6) with default settings. Nothing additional. There is no additional `setTab` except the one in document.php. The result is same - if you look at page source you will notice two spaces in front of the tags in the head section. I think that there should be two tabs.